# How to publish build output to network share with Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have modified my Build Pipeline to run jobs in parallel using multiple agents hosted on different build servers (VMs hosted in Azure).

The problem is that now I cannot use "Container" as the publishLocation value, because each build server should publish to the same drop folder.

So I would like to start using filePath. However what is the typical approach to this in Azure ? Is it possible to publish to the storage  ? Or do I have to create another dedicated VM to which I would publish the build outputs of each build machine ?  How to specify a VM in the filePath ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround ,you can switch `Artifact publish location` to `A file share` in Publish Pipeline Artifacts
task then specify your network drive folder path.

Specifying the path to the file share where you want to copy the files. The path must be a fully-qualified path or a valid path relative to the root directory of your repository. Publishing artifacts from a Linux or macOS agent to a file share is not supported.

[image]

Comment: What about nfs shares? Linux / macOS should be able to access those?